# How many points with integer coordinates lie either wholly inside or on the perimeter of triangle?

Tags: geometry, triangles, self-learning, coordinate-systems, integers

Triangle $OAB$ has vertices with coordinates $O=(0,0),A=(4,0),B=(0,2)$. As shown in the diagram, there are 9 points with integer coordinates that lie either wholly inside or on the perimeter of the triangle.[image: Triangle OAB]

Now triangle $PQR$ has the vertices with coordinates $P=(-24,17),Q=(15,-35),R=(100,169)$.

How many points with integer coordinates lie either wholly inside or on the perimeter of triangle $PQR$?

Answer:- I don't have any hint to answer this question.

If any member knows the answer, may reply with correct answer.

Comment: I think generally this is the setup of an integer programming problem. Not sure a good answer exists at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick%27s_theorem):  The area of the figure is the number of internal lattice points plus half the boundary lattice points minus one.

$$  A = i + \frac{b}{2} - 1  $$

and also the result of [another question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2956889/how-many-number-of-integer-coordinates-exists-between-a-line-segment-including) to count points on a line segment.  Use this to count the points on the three boundary segments (being sure to count the points on the vertices only once) to get $b$.